# how to create and read a text file,that is editable after setup by user?

Tags: c#, installation, file-access

I create a text file by using fileStream, I made the setup.exe and run it. then when I wanted to change its content by open the file manually and save, it was denied. the error was shown: "you do not have permission to open this file. see the owner of the file or an administrator to obtain permission".
my codes in the visual studio are:

```
FileStream myTfile = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\data\TextFile\Temperature.txt",
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite); 
lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\data\TextFile\Temperature.txt");
```

Comment: So, do you have access to the folder? What attribute does the file have? Did you ever close file?

Comment: yes, I have. all of my codes about that are here, and after these, I close the file named myTfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as Slava suggested it is a very good idea to use `FileStream` in a `using()` that makes sure that FileStream closes correctly:

```
using(FileStream myTfile = new FileStream(path)){
     // make your read write operations here
}
```

However, this is not the case with your problem. The problem is that the file you are trying to modify it, is in a path that needs more privilege to access and it is restricted. Many folders in System drive (usually C:) is like this that includes paths for specific user's Documents, Desktop, ... folders and many more.

The solution is:

**Option 1.** You may choose a path that is not restricted and doesn't need a special privilege like:

```
C:\Users\Public   // assuming drive C is the system drive
```

**Option 2.** Make your application run as administrator:

- To do this, in solution explorer right click and choose Add > New Item
- Select "Application Manifest File" 
  -Open the item you have just added and change `<requestedExecutionLevel>`

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: thank you so much. Now with option1, I should create the path manually, the textfile is created by my app and it is editable.

Comment: but about option 2, when I right-click on the solution and choose Add New Item, there is no "Application Manifest File" to choose

Answer (score 0):

Here you create or open a file:

```
FileStream myTfile = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + 
@"\data\TextFile\Temperature.txt",
FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

System will keep it open util you are done. When you are done you need to tell system to release resources associated with the file. To do that either use a *using* statement:

```
using(FileStream myTfile = new FileStream(path)){
     // your code here
}
```

Or close it manually after you are done with it:

```
myTfile.Close();
```

Comment: I had closed it manually. my problem was sth else. please read my problem again

Comment: You might try checking the permissions of the TextFile folder or parent folders. Try to delete and recreate them manually, see if the problem persists